# How to interpret entries from Exports tab in ProcessHacker

Tags: dll, libraries, processhacker

I use [ProcessHacker](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/) version 2.33 to inspect the functions which are exported by DLLs in running processes. In the screen-shot below you can see a few exported functions from a C++ application, along with their Ordinal number and virtual address (VA):

[image]

This is a pretty cool feature of ProcessHacker, which I was not able to find in ProcessExplorer. However, regarding the entries you can see in this screen-shot, I was not able to find what do the `?` (question marks) and the number, which prefixes the names of the functions, mean. Also, I'm not sure what the single and double `@` (at) symbols in the name, followed by a group of capital letters or number, mean.

**Question 1:** What do the symbols (`?, @`), number-prefix and capital letter suffixes represent? How can one interpret them?

**Question 2:** What does the "Ordinal" column mean?

**Question 3:** Does the "VA" column show the offset of the procedure entry point, with respect to the base address of the `.text` segment of the DLL? If not, what does it represent?

**Question 4:** How can one compute the absolute address of any function from the Exports tab?

Comment: Here is a quick comparison of the export of a DLL found by Process Hacker and the exports identified by IDA. Hopefully the below answers and the side by side will be helpful. http://i.stack.imgur.com/T7VYk.png

Comment: @alexanderh thanks for the photo. It sheds some light on the matter.

Comment: It's better to open new questions than add new ones.

Comment: @0xea I did want to do that, however, the title of the question and the intro + picture would have been the same for the new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are C++ name decorations.

> Name decoration usually refers to C++ naming conventions, but can apply to a number of C cases as well. By default, C++ uses the function name, parameters, and return type to create a linker name for the function.

See [Name Decoration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/deaxefa7.aspx) on MSDN for more info.

Question 2: Ordinals are just another way of making exports. You either export a function by name or by ordinal. It is unique in that binary only. You get functions by ordinals by using [GetProcAddress()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) just the same as you would with a name.

I could recommend ["Windows via C/C++"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0735624240) book for many more details about those mechanisms.

Comment: That page doesn't really offer a good explanation. OTOH, the remark at the bottom "There is currently no standard for C++ naming between compiler vendors or even between different versions of a compiler" is *crucial*. You can only guess what version was used by trying to decode.

Answer (score 2):

I'd  recommend loading the dll file into PE Explorer (View->Export), which will undecorate the names for you and show you the corresponding parameters/return value/calling convention.

You may also want to check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9177591/how-to-undecorate-name-from-decorated-name).